# Htaccess rewrite rule name same as folder's name

Tags: .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^photos/([^/.]*)/([^/.]*) photos.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L,QSA]
```

I have rewrite rule a page **photos.php**, however I have an folder call **photos/**

Here is the problem

because I rewrite rule so url will **show photos/23/imagesname**

but any images store inside of folder  **photos/myimage.jpg** will not show

anyone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you sure that the web browser isn't trying to access `photos/23/imagesname/photos/myimage.jpg` instead of `photos/myimage.jpg`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make sure MultiViews are off. Then tell the rule to ignore `real files and directories`. Try this rule.

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^photos/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ photos.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

Before your RewriteRule create a condition that will ignore the photos in your photos directory:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/photos/[0-9a-zA-Z_\-]+\.(gif|jpg|png)$
```

You may also want to add a dollar sign ($) at the end of your regular expression (after the second set of parentheses) to signify the end of your expression.

Comment: this works, but when i store images, I auto create sub folder

/photos/01/abc.jpg... /photos/02/def.jpg